# jquery eval a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

How do I go about using jQuery to post a request and view the result.

I have a format.js file that returns something like this if I enter it on the url of the browser.

```
document.write( '<object    id="player" name="YOUniversityTVPlayer"    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"    allowFullScreen="true">' );
```

and i use:

```
$.post(
    "format.js", function(data) {alert("success");alert(data);}
);
```

And I want the alert to show the result of the request, the format.js result

Comment: do you need the output of the document.write?

Comment: oddly no, in fact i just need the <object></object> part but I don't have any control over the js file and what it outputs. I just need to get the result and actually remove that document.write() and only use the <object> part.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `document.write` in the loaded script! When your script is eval-ed by `$.post`, the actual value of the parameter `data` is the result of the last expression statement of your script. As an example, consider this:

```
val r = eval("dosomethingelse(); 42"); // r is 42
```

If, for any reason, you cannot change the loaded script, you could always hijack `document.write`:

```
var oldwrite = document.write;
var mypreciousdata;
document.write = function (data) {mypreciousdata = data;}
// your $.post here
document.write = oldwrite;
```

But I do condemn those sort of actions...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do something different like saving

```
<object    id="player" name="YOUniversityTVPlayer"    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"    allowFullScreen="true">
```

in a file called fragment.html and get that using $.ajax and then use the fragment

```
$.ajax({
  url: "fragment.html",
  dataType: "html",
  method: "post",
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
     alert(data);
     //use the html
     $('#result').html(data);
  });
```

you could also use "script" as a dataType and have the script evalued on the go, but of course you'd need to change your script

Comment: that would be nice but I actually need what that js returns because it generates a unique <object></object> for each js request I make. The js file takes an argument and does several operations and returns an unique <object> based on my param. So i really need the js file result.